# How to render to a GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES?

Tags: opengl-es, render-to-texture

I need a way to render to a **GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES** texture. I tried binding the texture to a framebuffer but I got **GL_INVALID_ENUM** error. Here is some sample code:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &frameBuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer); 
glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, outTexHandle, 0); // I get GL_INVALID_ENUM here
// set viewport, uniforms and draw 
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
```

My final goal is to modify the camera frame using SurfaceTexture by applying some filters on it. Therefore, my shader program has both as input and output the same **GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES** texture. Is this possible? If not are there any workarounds? For my application it is essential that the output texture is **GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES**, I cant't use a GL_TEXTURE_2D texture.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot render to a `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` texture. `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` is the external texture which is rendered to by other devices such as the devices camera. You have read access to this texture. If you need to change how the texture is rendered then you will need to write a shader program to do so.

There are a number of steps you must perform before you can access the OES texture data. The external OES texture must be initialised in the following way:

```
int[] mTextureHandles = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, mTextureHandles, 0);
mTextureHandle = mTextureHandles[0];

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureHandles[0]);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
```

You then wrap OES texture in a `SurfaceTexture` object and set it to update for each frame. Your class must implement the `SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener` interface:

```
camTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureHandle);
camTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
```

When initialising the camera, you must point it to use the `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` like so:

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
try{
    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(camTexture);
}catch(IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now in your `public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture)` callback, you render to one of the `GL_TEXTURE` objects like so:

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
camTexture.updateTexImage();
renderFrame();
```

In your `renderFrame()` method you need to do the following:

1 - Set viewport

2 - Bind to the external texture: `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texId);`

3 - Set all of the variables for the shader program including transformation matrices

4 - Finally render the texture with a call to `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);`

If your goal is to change the way that the texture is rendered, you must implement a GLES shader program to do so. Here is an example of a simple texture vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
void main() {
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
    vTextureCoord = vec2(1.0 - aTextureCoord.s, aTextureCoord.t);
}
```

And here is the associated fragment shader:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
}
```

Note that the fragment shader has the `#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require` at the top of the shader file. This is very important, it is required to allow the shader to read from the `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` texture. You can now change the shader program to render the external texture data any way that you wish.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful - especially the part at the end about needing the #extension